# Using LINQ in C# for paginated results

Tags: c#, jquery, pagination

I'm looking for a design solution for a pattern that I am going to have to repeat quite a lot throughout a website I am designing. It is going to be ASP.NET MVC front-end, with C# WCF web services connecting using NHibernate to SQL database.

It's a social networking site so imagine facebook here to get a conceptual idea. What I'm looking for is an efficient and performant way to return paginated results of large datasets, for example a user may have 150 emails. I want to return them 10 at a time depending on what page theyre on, obviously only returning the 10 that relate to the page rather than having to load all 150 items into memory and only displaying 10 at a time as I think the user experience would be better to have a slightly longer delay in changing pages compared to a faster initial load. After all when do you look at emails 6 months old? The usual case is you only care about the first page of results anyway. Similarly a user may have had a number of interactions since their last login (eg your notifications feed on facebook) but again I only want to load n number of results at a time, but in this instance rather than having pages, you would click the "Display more" button which would then fetch the next N results, display them with another "display more" link and so forth you can keep clicking until you reach the end of the dataset. I can imagine they would both use the same design though as they are technically both paginated results, just with different UI output and flow.

Can anyone offer some advice on a good design to use for this, bearing in mind my data retrieval is using NHibernate Queryable or Enumerables? Would I want to be loading all data from DB in one hit then using an interator pattern to only return N rows from the service layer, keeping the rest of the list held in memory on the server open in the users session context so if I made another call to retrieve the next N rows, it would be held in place and keep returning N rows until the iterator finished, or would it be best to simply retrieve N rows from the database and return those, holding nothing in session context? I can see how to return top 10 results from Queryable as

```
var results = (from email in emails where email.UserId = userId).Take(10);
```

But I'm not sure how efficient this is, is this the fastest way of doing it? And furthermore I don't see how to start at a certain position, this will always only return the first 10, not say the second 10, or third 10 etc.

So I'm a bit unsure how the best way to proceed is and was hoping for some pointers and advice from people who have done something similar. Bearing in mind with my website performance is going to be of the essence so the user experience needs to be pretty sharp and interactive with refreshing new results. Basically if you were trying to simulate a facebook news feed/wall - how would you implement it with the above architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want your system to be scalable, you should keep your servers **stateless**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I want to be loading all the in one hit...

Definitely not, you only want to pull down the records you need, not the ones you *may* need.

> ...using an interator pattern to only return N rows from the service layer, keeping the rest of the list held in memory on the server open in the users session context...

Scalability goes right out the window with that idea.

> ...or would it be best to simply retrieve N rows from the database and return those, holding nothing in session context?

Now your starting to get on the right track...

In general, you want to let the database do as much as the querying as possible i.e. you don't want to hit the database to then have to further query the results (however, that's not always avoidable). In other words, you want to delegate most, if not all, the heavy lifting to the database.

You mentioned you are using NHibernate which is a pretty powerful ORM. The good news is that do a lot of the work for you in terms of query optimization/caching data etc. Like most ORM's nowadays, NHibernate uses deferred execution with it's queries so just watch out for things like hitting the database too early & choosing when to eager load data instead of performing multiple queries. There is a lot to learn with NHibernate, if you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read up about it before diving in it will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

> Bearing in mind with my website performance is going to be of the essence so the user experience needs to be pretty sharp and interactive with refreshing new results

In terms of the performance (I assume you mean page load speeds) you would just want to ajaxify your site i.e. load what needs to be loaded with the page, pull the rest in the background & update the page dynamically. To achieve the "refreshing new results" part you need to look at [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) the server and pulling down new data. I am pretty sure Facebook use a technique called [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) which essentially keeps an active request open with the server for a set amount of time so the data appears to happen "instantly". Polling is a different ball game all together though, it's about striking the balance of server load vs how "fresh" the data needs to be - that's something you would need to decide yourself and the answer to that is usually dependant on the type of data vs the hardware capabilities of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's very helpful. With NHibernate do you think there's always room to implement your own caching as well for performance or will I find when scaling that NHibernate already does it all pretty well for itself?

Comment: @user1122909 Definitely, NHibernate will only be useful in terms of caching DB data, you may want to implement your own type of caching e.g. Page/ViewData etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Skip` in combination with `Take`:

```
var results = (from email in emails where email.UserId = userId)
              .Skip((currentPage - 1) * 10)
              .Take(10);
```

---

About the web service: You really should make it a stateless web service. You could use the ASP.NET Web API for this. This enables you to build a RESTful web service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know any good links with an overview of RESTful web service design so I can familiarise myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are some links about it ([like this](http://hurtsmybrains.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/paging-with-linq/)) out there but I liked [this guy approach](https://github.com/danielcrenna/paging). I don't know if I'd use his PagedQueryable, but his [IPageable](https://github.com/danielcrenna/paging/blob/master/Paging/IPageable.cs), [IPagedEnumerable](https://github.com/danielcrenna/paging/blob/master/Paging/IPagedEnumerable.cs) and [PagedEnumerable](https://github.com/danielcrenna/paging/blob/master/Paging/PagedEnumerable.cs) are really interesting. Besides, his project introduction page may give you some ideas on how to roll your own pagination.